# How to Remove bootstrap table cell border color

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a bootsrap table. I removed some unnecessary cells. But therefore cell borders are displaying. I want to remove the table cell borders. It possible?

See the bootstrap table code:

Comment: Unclear what you're asking: You have not included the css for the classes you are using. Please follow  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

Aytt, I copied your code in my trial code and it works perfectly fine.

I think it's because I've added both bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap-theme.min.css

also include bootstrap.min.js file in your js folder. it helps.

here is screenshot of the code I ran:-->[sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8J5Z.png)

Comment: Is there anything causing this border at wordpress? I mean, wordpress is auto formatting tables? If yes, how can I remove? Any idea?